# Update table statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

have a great day to everyone.
I have some confusion about UPDATE TABLE statement in Oracle DB 12cr2.
Let's assume we have 3 users:

1. U1;
2. U2;
3. U3;

U1 has a table called TEST_1, and U2 and U3 both have UPDATE privilege on that table.

My question is that: **If U2 and U3 try to update same rows in that particular table at the same time what will happen? How Oracle will control such kind of processes?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure how the three accounts and update privileges are relevant to the question. Surely the same situation applies if three people all log in as `U1`?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson If three people all log in as U1 it will not what I asked for, it will just U1 has connected to the DB from three different sessions. But in this situation(if U1 updates same rows in that particular table at the same time from different three sessions) the answer will be the same as **Roberto Hernandez** said bellow. 
I think I could make your thoughts clear.

Comment: No, not really. Where does Roberto say it makes a difference how you connected? The first session to issue an update gets a lock, regardless of who they are. Subsequent sessions wait in line, regardless of who they are. Who they are is irrelevant for locking.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I didnot mean that **Roberto Hernandez** said that it makes difference how you connected, I say in your case also the answer will be as same as bellow (as you said too: **Subsequent sessions wait in line, regardless of who they are.**)

Comment: So why mention the three accounts at all? What difference does it make to the question?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I have had what happens if one user connected to DB from difference session: ( **Subsequent sessions will wait in line** ). But hadnot any **clear or certain knowledge** for my case. Is that make your thoughts clear?

Comment: And the answer was that the behaviour is the same with three user accounts as with one. I am curious about what difference you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the first answer already explains very well what is the locking mechanism, let me add a bit more information.

In your case, we are talking about Row Locks (TX). Row-level locks are primarily used to prevent two transactions from modifying the same row. When a transaction needs to modify a row, a row lock is acquired.

There is no limit to the number of row locks held by a statement or transaction, and Oracle does not escalate locks from the row level to a coarser granularity. Row locking provides the finest grain locking possible and so provides the best possible concurrency and throughput.

When two transactions ( updates in your case ) are attacking the same row, the first will acquire the lock , and it won't release it until it either commits or rollback. A system change number (SCN) which is a logical, internal time stamp used by Oracle Database will be assigned to each transactions. System Change Numbers or SCNs order events that occur within the database, which is necessary to satisfy the ACID properties of a transaction.

SCNs occur in a monotonically increasing sequence. Oracle Database can use an SCN like a clock because an observed SCN indicates a logical point in time and repeated observations return equal or greater values. If one event has a lower SCN than another event, then it occurred at an earlier time with respect to the database. Several events may share the same SCN, which means that they occurred at the same time with respect to the database.

Every transaction has an SCN. For example, if a transaction updates a row, then the database records the SCN at which this update occurred. Other modifications in this transaction have the same SCN. When a transaction commits, the database records an SCN for this commit.

Oracle Database increments SCNs in the system global area (SGA). When a transaction modifies data, the database writes a new SCN to the undo data segment assigned to the transaction. The log writer process then writes the commit record of the transaction immediately to the online redo log. The commit record has the unique SCN of the transaction. Oracle Database also uses SCNs as part of its instance recovery and media recovery mechanisms.

When two transactions occur at the very same time, for example the same second, the one which its timestamp is sooner is the one acquiring lock. Keep in mind that TIMESTAMP stores fractional_seconds_precision which specifies the number of digits in the fractional part of a SECOND. This fraction can be a number in the range 0 to 9.

Comment: Good explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In short One of the three users will acquire a lock on the table while updating it (whichever users executes the query first by micro secs differences) and rest of the two users have to wait for U1 to commit and release the lock, So now U2 or U3 will get updated data to work upon.

**Snippet from another article:**

COMMIT

When a COMMIT statement is issued to the database, the transaction has ended, and the following results are true:

All work done by the transaction becomes permanent.
Other users can see changes in data made by the transaction.
Any locks acquired by the transaction are released.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, with micro secs differences do you mean optimistic / pessimistic time estimations or what?

Comment: Just an example because somehow Oracle will figure out to give lock to which user.

Comment: Ok. I will wait for one more day to accept  your answer as right just for more information from others.